# DataGridView CheckBox ToolStripMenuItem - last CheckBox clicked not registering?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I recently changed my form to use toolStripMenuItems to execute processes instead of buttons. I bound the the existing btnWhatever_Click() to the Menu Item's Click event.

I have a single column of checkboxes to select which rows to process.  The last checkbox I click on is visibly checked, but is ignored as if it isn't when I run the processing from the menu instead of the button.  Before processing, I always count the number of checks to make sure the user knows how many rows they are processing.  It is always 1 less than it should be.

```
private int countApprovalChecks()
{
  //count approval check marks
  int ctr = 0;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAppManualReviewMatches.Rows)
  {
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[chkApprove.Name].Value) == true)
    {
      ctr++;
    }
  }
  return ctr;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the column index of the check box..I may have a solution for you

Comment: It's the first column which is probably 0 - but I am counting the checkboxes, which starts with 1 (I've been using C#/winforms for 2 days now, so if I'm wrong...)

Comment: I will give you provide you with a different way of doing it give me a sec I will post what I think should work for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing your grid is still in edit mode, which would affect the value of the row:

```
private int countApprovalChecks()
{
  dgvAppManualReviewMatches.EndEdit();

  //count approval check marks
  int ctr = 0;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAppManualReviewMatches.Rows)
  {
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[chkApprove.Name].Value) == true)
    {
      ctr++;
    }
  }
  return ctr;
}
```

When you had your code in the button, it would take the focus away from the grid, ending the edit mode, but your menu item does not take away the focus, so your edit mode is still continuing.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I love this forum, everyone is so helpful.  Sorry, can't upvote yet, or I would...